# trying to put a play audio method in my ActionListener

Tags: java, class, user-interface, audio, actionlistener

I am trying to put the play method within my `Audioapp` class inside my `ActionListener`, I tried putting it in but got errors.

I have read the javadoc on `ActionListener` but could not find it

This is my audio:

```
public class Audioapp extends JApplet // find out how to implement play method into action listener?
{
    public class Sound // Holds one audio file
    {
        private AudioClip song; // Sound player
        private URL songPath; // Sound path
        Sound(String filename)
        {
            try
            {
                songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),"G:\\Uni\\Programming\\Rolling assignements\\Week0\\Programming week21");  // This is the place were im getting error
                song = Applet.newAudioClip(songPath); // Load the Sound
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();} 
        }
        public void playSound()
        {
            song.play(); // Play
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `actionListener`:

```
class PlayStoHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String computerRand = sps.computerChoice();
        txtComputerRand.setText(computerRand);
        String result = sps.play(Sps.ROCK);
        txtResult.setText(result);

        scis.setVisible(false);
        open.setVisible(false);
        stone.setVisible(true);
        pap.setVisible(false);
        win.setVisible(false);
        none.setVisible(false);
        lose.setVisible(false);

        if (result == "User Wins"){
            win.setVisible(true);

                              song.play(); // here i tried putting the song.play in this if section, the error I got was "song cannot be resolved"
        }

        else if (result == "Draw"){
            none.setVisible(true);
        }
        else {
            lose.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

I'm a beginner so it's most probably a very stupid basic error

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1) Can you get the bloody code formatting right?!? 2) *"..but got errors."*  Like ..what?  Copy/paste these things and do not make us guess. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 4) Why is this an applet at all?  They are a PITA to develop, and too advanced for newbies.

Comment: "song cannot be resolved"

Comment: In your action listener, in the if statements, ( <String> == "things") makes no sense. Try the .equals () method, String.equals (" Things").

Answer (score 1):

```
songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),"G:\\Uni\\Programming\\Rolling assignements\\Week0\\Programming week21");
```

The URL constructor expects the second string to represent a relative URL, whereas you have put a file path.  URLs always have forward slashes, and a `file:` based URL there would make little sense (the WAV is hosted on your site, not the HD of the end user).

If the applet is being loaded by HTML at the root of the site with no `codebase` declared in the HTML, and the wav is called  `moo.wav` and is located in a sub-directory named `Week0/Programming week21` the correct path would be:

```
songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),"Week0/Programming week21/moo.wav");
```

But to make things a lot simpler, at least for the moment, put the HTML, the applet *and* the clip in the ***same directory*** and use:

```
songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),"moo.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

`song` is private. You created a method to play the sound so use it.

Get the instance of your `Audioapp` and run the `playSound()` method.